# Closure parameter not receiving the parameters, instead just it on the side

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures

working with recursion and closures but not receiving the correct output.
The recursion block works correctly to take out elements and then add them to a total.

but when I try to implement the closure to the problem is doesn't work and the output is just the function instead of the correct output

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function add(arr, total = 0) {
    if (arr.length === 0) return total;
    // console.log(total, 'total')
    numberToAdd = arr[0];
    // console.log(numberToAdd, 'number to be added to the total')
    arr.shift();
    // console.log(arr, 'array after taking out the first element', arr.length); 
    // console.log('total before recursion', total)

    return num + add(arr, total + numberToAdd);

}

addTo15 = add(arr)

console.log(addTo15(100))

/** expected output: 115
 * 
 * instead this outputs
 * 
 * 100function(num) {
        return num + add(arr, total + numberToAdd) ; 
    }
*/
```

Comment: Is there a function named `num` somewhere not shown in the post? Also `numberToAdd` hasn't been declared so it becomes a `window` property when running code in sloppy mode. If `num` is defined and set to a number then `addTo15()` errors because it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear to me, but my best guess is that you want to do something like this:

```js
const addArrTo = ([n, ...ns]) => (num) =>
  n == undefined
    ? num
    : addArrTo (ns) (num + n)

const addTo15 = addArrTo ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

console .log (addTo15 (100))
```

which can also be written like this, if it's more familiar:

```js
const addArrTo = (arr) => (num) =>
  arr .length == 0
    ? num
    : addArrTo (arr .slice (1)) (num + arr [0])
```

or even as

```js
function addArrTo (arr) {
  return function (num) {
    return arr .length == 0
      ? num
      : addArrTo (arr .slice (1)) (num + arr [0])
  }
}
```

Each of these versions is a function that accepts an array of numbers and returns a function.  The returned function takes a starting number, and then recursively calls itself, adding the current number from the input array to the running total.